# Melhores práticas ao filtrar uma consulta com EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api

Possuo um método em web api que recebe um model de um formulário de busca e de acordo com seus valores, ele passa a filtrar o resultado desta busca, conforme exemplo abaixo.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Buscar([FromBody]BuscarModel model)
    {
         Chamados resultado = chamadoServico.Buscar();

         if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Foo))
              resultado = resultado.Where(e => e.Foo == model.Foo);
         if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Bar))
              resultado = resultado.Where(e => e.Bar == model.Bar);

         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultado);
    }
```

O código funciona conforme o esperado até adicionar um filtro a uma `navigationProperty`. Por exemplo

```
 if(model.Foobar != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Foobar.Foo))
        resultado = resultado.Where(e => e.Foobar.Foo == model.Foobar.Foo);
```

Neste momento, a exceção `EntityCommandExecutionException` é levantada com a seguinte mensagem:

> Já existe um DataReader aberto associado a este Command que deve ser
>   fechado primeiro.

Esta é a forma correta de se criar um mecanismo de busca através de filtros?
O que pode ser feito para evitar que a exceção seja levantada? Existe outra forma além de executar um `toList()` antes da chamada a navigationProperty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Esta é a forma correta de se criar um mecanismo de busca através de filtros?

É. Na verdade é preciso uma explicação para o entendimento do erro.

Quando você monta uma consulta em dois lugares diferentes através do Entity Framework, o que acontece é que uma conexão fica aberta esperando sua resolução, que normalmente se dá chamando `ToList()` ou `AsEnumerable()`, ou ainda algo que resolva o objeto de `IQueryable<>` para outra coisa.

Ao realizar a mesma coisa no filtro, o que você faz (sem querer, lembrando) é montar uma filtragem destacada da primeira, que já possui uma conexão aberta esperando a execução. Por isso o erro.

> O que pode ser feito para evitar que a exceção seja levantada?

A maneira ruim de resolver é usando `MultipleActiveResultSets` na *connection string*, mas isso não resolve todos os casos.

A maneira boa é resolvendo a pesquisa com `ToList()` ou `AsEnumerable()`. Infelizmente não dá para gerar SQL com `Where` a partir de dois lugares diferentes. É uma limitação do framework.

> Existe outra forma além de executar um `toList()` antes da chamada a `navigationProperty`?

Pelo explicado acima, não, mas não veja isso como algo ruim. A filtragem em *Controller* é uma montagem de SQL, e a do filtro uma filtragem em memória. Só ficará ruim se o resultado do SQL for muito grande.

Comment: Estava querendo evitar justamente por causa da possível massa de dados, mas deixando este filtro como o último a ser efetuado pode diminuir a carga de processamento no SQL.

Comment: O ideal é você deixar o máximo de filtros que puder em *Controller* e filtrar uma massa menor em memória dentro do filtro. É uma limitação sim, que espero que resolvam em futuras versões.